# ShellExeute Format DOS command

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, dos

I am trying to execute DOS's FORMAT command using Windows ShellExecute API. I am not sure how I'm supposed to run DOS commands for ShellExecute. Currently I'm using the following Code:

```
DWORD returnCode=0;
TCHAR Command[1024];
_stprintf_s(Command, _T("Format M: /FS:FAT32 /Q /X /V:RED"));

SHELLEXECUTEINFO sexi = {0};
sexi.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
sexi.hwnd = NULL;
sexi.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
sexi.lpFile = _T("cmd.exe");
sexi.lpParameters = Command;
sexi.nShow = SW_SHOW;

if(ShellExecuteEx(&sexi))
{
    DWORD wait = WaitForSingleObject(sexi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    if(wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        GetExitCodeProcess(sexi.hProcess, &returnCode);
}
```

Running this piece of code will just hang as WaitForSingleObject will wait until the cmd window is closed. I have tried using the Command string as the SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpFile but that failed.

And even when executing this code, It just opens a CMD window without executing the format command.

I need to execute the FORMAT command silently without showing any console window. I am using DiskPart to Format the drive on Win7 but for XP I'm stuck with FORMAT.

Can someone help please?!!!

Regards

P.S. I need also to override the "Insert New Disk" prompt that shows when you execute a FORMAT command so that the user would not have to click enter for the format process to start.

Comment: can you try with `sexi.nShow = SW_HIDE`?

Comment: It just hides the console window and it keeps waiting.... And besides I dont think the code above is actually running format since it just opens a cmd window but i dont get the format prompt message that tells me to insert a media..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SHFormatDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This will still show you a dialog box. Or check the [Volume Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) which seems to do want you want.

Comment: Thanks, will check the Volume Class.. as for SHFormatDrive it does the trick but only up to XP SP2 which leaves SP3 unmanageable.